# My mapView dosen't show the map just shows the overlay items

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, xamarin.android, md5

I already tried to generate my key in https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup with too much MD5 many times but doesn't work .
When a try MapView using 
`var mapIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, geoUri)`
it works but i can't put my overlay items .
I need to use my MapView from layout but just show lines and overlayitems.
I tried use the example HelloMap in cellphone but happen the same thing doesn't show map just overlay items.

Comment: have you added the key in your xml file ?

Comment: does your LogCat output something like "no Maps-Api key?" you have to use keytool with the `-v` option to output md5, and NOT just shaXXX

Comment: Show us: Manifest, mapview xml or code, logcat message...

Comment: It may be coincidence but this happened to me on Monday - it just didn't show anything... could it be a win8 or vs2012 difference? (For reference I've previously shipped several MonoDroid apps with maps)

Comment: i'm using win8 and vs2012 and monodroid too.
This problem that happened on Monday to you , have you already solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!!!! \o

Instead of generate the release .apk i publish the .apk as i will publish into store !
My MapView worked on both 3g and wi-fi.
Thanks everyone for help-me!

Answer (score 2):

Either you don't have a valid key, or you forgot to put the uses-library line in your manifest.

Comment: I put my key in xml and i also tried in runtime but dosen't work.

Comment: Are you sure your key properly matches the debug signing key on this computer (or release signing key if you're building release)?  And do you have <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> in your manifest?

Comment: i used <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in manifest .
It has any difference to generate release or debug key if has how can i do to generate in release?

Comment: When you requested a key for the google maps api, it required you to give them a hash of your signing key.  If you gave them your debug key and you sign with your release key, the has won't match and it won't turn on maps.  Same if you did it the other way around.  The hash you give them must match the signing key for your app.

Comment: How can i generate my release key? 
Because i just know how to generate the debug key.
I used this site https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup
to put my MD5 and generate my key.
I don't know how i can generate my key to release my application

Answer (score 1):

I saw the exact same thing on Monday this week - but haven't returned to the project since to debug it.

My suspicion for me is that this might be a VS2012 or Windows8 bug as I've previously shipped several maps apps from this same PC (before VS2012 and Win8)

If you've got this reproducible right now, I think you should log this with Xamarin - support@xamarin.com or http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: This is weird because i think the System Operation can't alter the release method. 
I don't have Win7 now to test this. Could you test it?

Comment: Not here either. Send to Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

To generate the keystore i used

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20>keytool -genkey -alias umAlias -keystore C:\localParaoArquivo\nomedoarquivo.keystore

to see md5 i used

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\localParaoArquivo\nomedoarquivo.keystore

I put my key in xml and i also tried in runtime but doesn't work.

what is the difference between MD5 and SHA1?
I use in my manifest

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
```

Comment: MD5 and SHA1 are completely different hashing algorithms.  I forget off the top of my head what all the differences are, but if Google expects one format and you give them another it will not work.